# external JS file + jquery + css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `tr` in my html like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some_file.css"> // at the head

<c:forEach var="some_variable" items="some_items">
      <tr class="some_class"> some_variable </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I also have a submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="onSave()"/>
```

The on click with the button will trigger a function in external javascript

```
$( '.some_class' ).each( function() {
    if( some condition which involve '.some_class' ) {
       $( this ).addClass('another_class');
    } else {
       $( this ).removeClass('another_class');
    } 
});
```

The another class is from an external css which have

```
.another_class {
    background-color: '#ffffb4';
}
```

I don't get it why the tr doesn't change the background-color when I added a class to the `tr`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you use a browser dev tool to see whether or not the added style is applied? maybe the class is added, but it is not used?

Comment: I tried console.log( $(this).attr('class') ) and it's printing some_class another_class

Comment: so your class is added to the elements. Now you need to find out why the style is not applied. Probably to to with the style [precedent](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)...
You could try to add !important to the class to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would correct your input which has unclosed value attribute:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit onclick="onSave()"/>
```

change to

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="onSave()"/>
```

you are missing **td** element in your row

```
<tr class="some_class"> <td>some_variable</td> </tr>
```

Ahh and remove apostrophes from your style rule like below:

```
.another_class {
    background-color: #ffffb4;
}
```

And basic JSFiddle with your problem -> http://jsfiddle.net/ApfJz/24/

Comment: A yeah that my typing error here, sorry for that. See my update i fixed it. But still that won't fix my problem. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Posting here your HTML snippet would help, then we can try to check what is wrong

Comment: The code is long so I only post the structure it self. The `td` is not really related to my problem i only want to change the color of the whole row on a specific condition. When i tried in jquery the `.css( background-color: some color )` it work out well. But my tech lead saids the proper approach is to put the style on the external css file so actually i'm not that familiar with this.

Comment: Now I know, remove apostrophes from your CSS background-color, see updated answer

Comment: I removed the quotes but still have no effect.

Comment: and why you don't have td element in your tr? was already in my jsFiddle, now added also to my answer